# Shadowbox opening an external URL gives a broken page

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

First of all, sorry about my poor english.

I'm having problems with shadowbox when I need to open a external URL. I can open the page, but it is full of black spaces. This happens with google too. I tried to open the google and all the page is black.

[image: https://s23.postimg.org/6llip9emj/shadowbox.png]

So, I'm trying to resolve this with the options that shadowbox gives, but there's nothing that I can set on it. The problem happens with IE, Chrome and FF.

edit: The code that I'm using:

```
Shadowbox.init({
        skipSetup: true,
        modal: true,
    });

$(window).load(function () {

        // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
        Shadowbox.open({
            content: 'https://shopline.itau.com.br/shopline/shopline.aspx',
            player: "iframe",
            type: "iframe",
            title: "Main",
            height: 480,
            width: 720
        });

    });
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that opens the box

Answer (score 0):

I Found it.

Probably because the page I want to open is in great part white, shadowbox is replacing it.

I used ColorPix to find out the color of the black spaces, and it's #060606, and I found on the CSS this:

```
#sb-body,#sb-loading{background-color:#060606;}
```

So, i changed it to `#ffffff` and it works! now it doesn't replace the blank parts for black.

I don't know if this is correct, but it works for me. :)